# What is the type of a JSON object in python?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary, types

I'm new to JSON. I have a dictionary, I convert it to a JSON object using

```
            myJsonObject = json.dumps(myDictionary)
```

But then If I check the type, I get `<type 'str'>`

***Is string is the expected output for a JSON object?***

PS: Python 2.7

***Update:*** How can I get a JSON type, if dumps is not the correct way?

Comment: What's a "JSON type"? Usually JSON is used for communicating (e.g. between back-end Python and front-end JavaScript). It doesn't make sense to pass objects between them, so a JSON string is sent since it's a common literal object format that both languages have the tools to parse.

Comment: JSON is a way of encoding things as strings, so converting something to JSON means converting it to a string. So I'm not sure why you're expecting something other than a string here. What sort of thing do you want to get back, and why?

Comment: @TannerSwett, thanks for the comment. I was expecting JSON, because I'm trying to do a simple HTTP POST using requests. And the payload should be JSON. So I tried with a python dictionary but I get HTTP 500.

Comment: If I'm understanding right, you should be able to take the string that `json.dumps` gives you and send it via HTTP. Does that sound like what you want to do?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Of course, this is called ["Serialization"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) - you are [dumping a Python data structure into a JSON formatted string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps):

> `json.dumps()`
>
> Serialize obj to a JSON formatted str using this [conversion table](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#py-to-json-table).

If you load a JSON string with `loads()`, this would be "deserialization" and you would get a Python list or a dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

The N of JSON is for Notation ; it is, indeed, a data format specification. A JSON object is usually intended to be used as a storage or inter-process communication format. That's why it is in Python the universal flat format accepted by write() : a string object.

You can print it to screen, save it to a file, or communicate it to another program to verify it is correct and containing expected data.